# Mesillas Yesharim in One Chart?

Tags: synagogue, mussar-ethics, publications, mesilas-yesharim

Years ago, I saw a printed chart hanging in a shul titled "Mesillas Yesharim in One Chart," or something very similar. I have been searching online for this but cannot find anywhere. Is anyone able to share this chart or direct me to it?

Comment: I have such a chart in Hebrew if you're interested.

Comment: Thank you, Harel. This is helpful to have and while it isn't the same format, it might be the same content as the chart I had seen (didn't examine too closely and it was a long time ago).

Comment: I made that chart available at http://aishdas.org/MesilasYesharimChart.pdf